# How to play a sound continuously without break?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am trying to play a vehicle driven sound in a browser based game (continuously without break).

My .wav file length is 1 second and has same frequency from beginning to end. But sound takes a little break before next iteration. 

Here is code:

```
function playSound()
{
    //alert("");
    myAudio = new Audio('http://ithmbwp.com/feedback/SoundsTest/sounds/tank_driven.wav'); 
    if (typeof myAudio.loop == 'boolean')
    {
        myAudio.loop = true;
    }
    else
    {
        myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();
        }, false);
    }
    myAudio.volume = 0.3;
    myAudio.play();
}
```

Can anyone help me to play the sound continuously?

#### Edition

You can visit my page [here](http://ithmbwp.com/feedback/SoundsTest/) to observe the problem.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  playSound();
};

function playSound()
{
 //alert("");
 myAudio = new Audio('http://ithmbwp.com/feedback/SoundsTest/sounds/tank_driven.wav'); 
 if (typeof myAudio.loop == 'boolean')
 {
  myAudio.loop = true;
 }
 else
 {
  myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
   this.currentTime = 0;
   this.play();
  }, false);
 }
 myAudio.volume = 0.3;
 myAudio.play();
}
```

```html
<h3 style="font-family:verdana;">Please listen the sound break.</h3>
<h3 style="font-family:verdana;">It should be continuous.</h3>
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in console

Comment: There is not error in the console. My problem is the break of sound before next iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the AudioContext API and its [bufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) interface, to have seamlessly looped sounds.

Note that you'll also need your audio to be correctly edited to avoid crackles and sound clips, but yours seems good.

```js
const aCtx = new AudioContext();
let source = aCtx.createBufferSource();
let buf;
fetch('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/knpo4d2yooe2u4h/tank_driven.wav') // can be XHR as well
  .then(resp => resp.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buf => aCtx.decodeAudioData(buf)) // can be callback as well
  .then(decoded => {
    source.buffer = buf = decoded;
    source.loop = true;
    source.connect(aCtx.destination);
    check.disabled = false;
  });

check.onchange = e => {
  if (check.checked) {
    source.start(0); // start our bufferSource
  } else {
    source.stop(0); // this destroys the buffer source
    source = aCtx.createBufferSource(); // so we need to create a new one
    source.buffer = buf;
    source.loop = true;
    source.connect(aCtx.destination);
  }
};
```

```html
<label>play audioBuffer</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" disabled><br><br>
Just to compare <audio src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/knpo4d2yooe2u4h/tank_driven.wav" loop controls>
```

Or with your snippet :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  playSound();
};

function playSound() {
  if (AudioContext) {
    out.textContent = "yeah now it's continuous !!!";
    playAsAudioBuffer();
  } else {
    out.textContent = "you should consider updating your browser...";
    playNormally();
  }
}

function playAsAudioBuffer() {
  var aCtx = new AudioContext();
  // here is the real audioBuffer to sound part
  function ondecoded(buf) {
    var source = aCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buf;
    source.loop = true;
    var gainNode = aCtx.createGain();
    gainNode.gain.value = .3; // here you set the volume
    source.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(aCtx.destination);
    source.start(0);
  }

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    aCtx.decodeAudioData(this.response, ondecoded);
  };
  xhr.onerror = playNormally;
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.open('get', 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/knpo4d2yooe2u4h/tank_driven.wav');
  xhr.send();
}

// An ugly workaround in case of old browsers
function playNormally() {
  var myAudios = [new Audio('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/knpo4d2yooe2u4h/tank_driven.wav')];
  myAudios.push(new Audio(myAudios[0].src));
  myAudios.forEach(function(a){
    a.addEventListener('timeupdate', checkTime);
    a.volume = 0.3;
    });
   
  function checkTime(){
    if(this.currentTime > this.duration - 0.4){
      startNext(this);
      }
    }
  var current = 0;
  function startNext(el){
    current = (current + 1) % 2;
    myAudios[current].play();
    el.currentTime = 0;
    el.pause();
    }
  myAudios[0].play();
}
```

```html
<h3 id="out"></h3>
```

Comment: @Rashid, do you allow me to copy your audio file on my dropbox account so that I can use it in an edit ?

Comment: @Rashid, so in absence of your response, I took the liberty to do so, since you linked to it in your question, but feel free to tell me to remove it if you mind.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kaiido. Its okey

Answer (score 3):

Bee Cool, just use few lines code

```js
window.onload = function() {
  playSound();
};

function playSound()
{
var myAudio = new Audio('http://ithmbwp.com/feedback/SoundsTest/sounds/tank_driven.wav'); 

myAudio.volume = 0.3 ;

var tank_driven_sound = setInterval(function()
{
 myAudio.currentTime = 0;
 myAudio.play();
}, 800);

}
```

```html
<h3 style="font-family:verdana;">Please listen, it's continuous.</h3>
```

Comment: Just for fun, try to scroll over the page while playing your sound... setInterval is not reliable.