# adding sound "volume" to a bit of javascript code (audiocontext)

Tags: javascript, audio, volume

I have this little javascript that I have working, it plays a tone for 30 seconds.  I wanted to see if it was possible to modify it so that it would play at say, half volume instead (it's just too loud).  I have researched and found "gain" node information, but I looked at the examples and honestly I'm a noob with javascrip and I don't fully understand the examples I saw.

Here is what I have so far (it works good, I just want to "volume" it down some)

```js
function myFunction(frequency, duration, callback) {

var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
duration = 30000 / 1000;     // the 10000 used to be 'duration' 
oscillator.type = 'square';
oscillator.frequency.value = 500; // value in hertz
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
oscillator.onended = callback;
oscillator.start(0);
oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + duration);
}
```

Can anyone help me modify this so I have a volume parameter I can tweak until it is right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386277/how-to-control-the-sound-volume-of-audio-buffer-audiocontext

Comment: I looked that this and I see what you mean, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

### Documentation

The documentation for what you are trying to do can be found under [`BaseAudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext), specifically the [`BaseAudioContext.createGain()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createGain) method.

The MDN documentation is lacking a little in that it only provides snippets that will not work as is. As such, an overly simplified example is given below, bearing in mind that this may not be best practice.

### Explanation

The oscillator and gain control are both audio nodes. As such, you should picture them in a signal chain like that given below.

[image: Web Audio Signal Chain]

The oscillator node passes through the gain node which passes through to the audio context.

#### Solution

Using your current format, as self contain snippet is given below ([see jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/u80x4s3f/))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
        gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        var gain = 0.1;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(gain, audioCtx.currentTime);
    </script>
</head>
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<body>

<div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
        Click me
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------      
        var duration = 0.5; // in seconds
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
        oscillator.type = 'square';
        oscillator.frequency.value = 500;
        oscillator.connect(gainNode);
        oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime);
        oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + duration);
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
</script>
</body>
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
</html>
```

#### Best practice

For best practice, I would suggest you should avoid recreating nodes over and over again. Rather, I would simply turn the gain up for a short period, then turn it back down, an example of which is given below.
As far as I can tell, there is no envelope generator node for WebAudio, but you could use [`.linear​Ramp​ToValue​AtTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime) if needed.

NOTE: This is not currently working in Safari.
([see jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kuvphrx2/))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Edit These
        var gain = 0.1;
        var duration = 1000;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------  
        var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
        oscillator.type = 'square';
        oscillator.frequency.value = 500;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        oscillator.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.0, audioCtx.currentTime); // turned off by default
        oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime);
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    </script>
</head>
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<body>

<div>
    <button onclick="soundOn()">
        Click me
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    function mute()
    {
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.0, audioCtx.currentTime);
    }
    function soundOn()
    {
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(gain, audioCtx.currentTime);
        setTimeout(mute,duration);
    }
</script>
</body>
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
</html>
```

### Further Resources

If you are struggling with interacting with audio context in this was, I would suggest trying out a library such as [p5.js](https://p5js.org) and the [p5.sound library](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.sound).

Look at the https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Oscillator to see whether it is a more intuitive approach.