# Video Flicker inside HTML canvas when looping

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

I'am trying to display a video inside a `canvas` and to `loop` the video. The issue sometimes happen when looping the video. Before playing the video again the video flicker for one frame. It's doesn't happen all the time and I don't get what's going on.

Here is the code

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let src = "https://i.imgur.com/5ZiAeSX.mp4";
let video = document.createElement("video");
video.src = src;
video.muted = true;
video.play();

video.onended = () => {
  video.play();
};

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

You can also try the `fiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eLwzbqn9/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because looping a MediaElement is never a seamless operation. 
This is particularly audible when [looping audio media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968873/how-to-play-a-sound-continuously-without-break/42970609#).

Normally, when played in a <video> we don't see it because the browser just pauses the video rendering for this short lapse of time, and our brain simply ignores the few frames that are paused and concentrate rather on all the ones that do move.

However, in your case it becomes very visible because you do clear the canvas anyway, but there is no video frame to be drawn on top of it. So it causes a big white flash.

A simple fix is to check whether the `currentTime` is `0` and to not redraw during this time:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let src = "https://i.imgur.com/5ZiAeSX.mp4";
let video = document.createElement("video");
video.src = src;
video.muted = true;
video.play();

let missed_frames = 0; // only for demo
video.onended = () => {
  video.play();
  // only for demo
  setTimeout(() => {
  _log.textContent = 'missed ' + missed_frames +' frames while looping';
  missed_frames = 0;
  }, 200);
};


function render() {
  if(video.currentTime) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  // only for demo
  else {
    missed_frames++;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```css
#_log { color: white; position: absolute; }
```

```html
<pre id="_log"></pre>
<canvas></canvas>
```

An harder fix if you really need to loop seamlessly would be to use a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) object, but if not really needed, that's a bit cumbersome to set in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can set viedo.loop to true and avoid the part when you ask your video to go on playing.

I've did the trick this way :

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let src = "https://i.imgur.com/5ZiAeSX.mp4";
let video = document.createElement("video");
video.src = src;
video.muted = true;
video.videoHeight = '500px'; // returns the intrinsic height of the video
video.videoWidth =  '100px'; // returns the intrinsic width of the video
video.play();
video.loop = true

/* video.onended = () => {
  video.play();
}; */

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

this is why your video flicker, it doesn't loop, it just replay again and again.
give it a try ;)

Comment: Doesnt change anything

Comment: Is it the paused time we see on the right you call flicker ? Because I can't see the video flickering at all, I only see it pausing on the middle of its play. to make it more symetric, you can either remove this pause time from the video, or make it sleep for like 1sec before each replay, but this one solution is hacky

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved,  actually it depends on the video, if the video isn't precise duration like 4:0s and it's 3:97 instead it flicker in the last frame. Doesn't seem to happen on the fiddle because I put the wrong video

Comment: ok ! and you can still use video.loop = true, it seems to do the same thing but with less code ;)